# Single Logout using HTTP-POST via back channel

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml, keycloak

Keycloak, WSO2 and some other SSO IDP servers offer a possibility of "Single Logout" without forcing browser to redirect to every SP where current user is logged in by sending the `<LogoutRequest>` over HTTP-POST via back channel.

Unfortunately this does not work if SSO integration in the service is implemented using **spring-security-saml2-core** library (we are using Keycloack).

All I could figure out from the log file on the SP side was:

```
[2016-01-13 12:50:56.867] [DEBUG] [org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter] - Received logout request is invalid, responding with error
org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLStatusException: No user is logged in
    at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl.processLogoutRequest(SingleLogoutProfileImpl.java:168)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.processLogout(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.doFilter(SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter.java:102)

...
```

The application that uses Spring SAML extension is deployed on the Tomcat 7. It seems that `<LogoutRequest>` when sent via back-end channel does not have a browser session cookie, and user application session cannot be identified, so user cannot be logged out and the application session of the user will not be invalidated.

However the `<LogoutRequest>` contains the global SSO session identifier which can uniquely identify the application session. But this does not happen.

Is this behavior of the Spring SAML library intended by desing: do not support back-end communication during Single Logout? or am I missing something and the desired behavior can be configured?

Note: I understand that according to SAML specification HTTP-POST and HTTP-Redirect bindings are intended to be carried via User Agent (web browser), however broad support from SSO IDP servers made me ask this question :)

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE:** According to Vladimir Schäfer's comment in the [SES-162 ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SES-162) it seems to be an intended library behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible to carry out `<LogoutRequest>` over HTTP-POST via back channel using Spring-SAML library.

This behavior is against SAML specification and according to Vladimir Schäfer's comment in the [SES-162 ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SES-162) it will not be supported by Spring-SAML.

SOAP binding is meant for backend channel, but as it is noted by @meetarun it is not implemented in Spring-SAML library at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

In Spring-SAML, Single Logout is currently supported with HTTP-Redirect and HTTP-POST bindings. SOAP binding is not available.  Refer : [Spring SAML Global Logout](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-logout)

Back channel is not supported in spring-saml